# Remove specific rows from CSV file in python

Tags: python, date, csv

I am trying to remove rows with a specific ID within particular dates from a large CSV file.

The CSV file contains a column [3] with dates formatted like "1962-05-23" and a column with identifiers [2]: "ddd:011232700:mpeg21:a00191".

Within the following date range:

- 01-01-1951 to 12-31-1951
- 07-01-1962 to 12-31-1962
- 01-01 to 09-30-1963
- 7-01 to 07-31-1965
- 10-01 to 10-31-1965
- 04-01-1966 to 11-30-1966
- 01-01-1969 to 12-31-1969
- 01-01-1970 to 12-31-1989

I want to remove rows that contain the ID ddd:11*

I think I have to create a variable that contains both the date range and the ID. And look for these in every row, but I'm very new to python so I'm not sure what would be an eloquent way to do this.

This is what I have now. -**CODE UPDATED**

```
import csv
import collections
import sys
import re
from datetime import datetime

csv.field_size_limit(sys.maxsize)

dateranges = [("01-01-1951","12-31-1951"),("07-01-1962","12-31-1962")]
dateranges = list(map(lambda dr: tuple(map(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x,"%m-%d-%Y"),dr)),dateranges))


def datefilter(x):
    x = datetime.strptime(x,"%Y-%m-%d")
    for r in dateranges:
        if r[0]<=x and r[1]>=x: return True
    return False

writer = csv.writer(open('filtered.csv', 'wb'))
for row in csv.reader('my_file.csv', delimiter='\t'):
    if datefilter(row[3]):
        if not row[2].startswith("dd:111"):
            writer.writerow(row) 
    else: 
        writer.writerow(row)
writer.close()
```

Comment: You can make `list` of those certain fields which fulfill your criteria and then write to the file. What is the problem with above code?

Comment: and for matching the `id` you can use `regex`

Comment: I'm just not sure how to finalize it. Basically, how to make a list of dates? How to write back to the original file. For the ID I will manage.

Comment: Please give me a sample set and post it here or any link of sample

Comment: @NikhilParmar here is a sample set: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/279252/mwevers_example_2016.01.02-07.25.55.csv -- not all dates might be included in this file (to keep it small)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would approach that, but it may not be the best method.

```
from datetime import datetime
dateranges = [("01-01-1951","12-31-1951"),("07-01-1962","12-31-1962")]
dateranges = list(map(lambda dr: tuple(map(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x,"%m-%d-%Y"),dr)),dateranges))

def datefilter(x):
    # The date format is different here to match the format of the csv
    x = datetime.strptime(x,"%Y-%m-%d")
    for r in dateranges:
        if r[0]<=x and r[1]>=x: return True
    return False

with open(main_file, "rb") as fp:
    root = csv.reader(fp, delimiter='\t')
    result = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for row in root:
        if datefilter(row[3]):
            # use a regular expression or any other means to filter on id here
            if row[2].startswith("dd:111"): #code to remove item
```

What I have done is create a list of tuples of your date ranges (for brevity, I only put 2 ranges in it), and then I convert those into datetime objects.

I have used maps for doing that in one line: first loop over all tuples in that list, applying a function which loops over all entries in that tuple and converts to a date time, using the tuple and list functions to get back to the original structure.  Doing it the long way would look like:

```
dateranges2=[]
for dr in dateranges:
    dateranges2.append((datetime.strptime(dr[0],"%m-%d-%Y"),datetime.strptime(dr[1],"%m-%d-%Y"))
dateranges = dateranges2
```

Notice that I just convert each item in the tuple into a datetime, and add the tuples to the new list, replacing the original (which I don't need anymore).

Next, I create a datefilter function which takes a datestring, converts it to a datetime, and then loops over all the ranges, checking if the value is in the range.  If it is, we return True (indicating this item should be filtered), otherwise return False if we have checking all ranges with no match (indicating that we don't filter this item).

Now you can check out the id using any method that you want once the date has matched, and remove the item if desired.  As your example is constant in the first few characters, we can just use the string startswith function to check the id.  If it is more complex, we could use a regex.

Comment: I changed the function to match the csv format.  Note that the format of the date used in the datefilter function should match the csv.  The format used for processing the list of ranges should match your range specifications.

Comment: @Matthew. I get a list index out of range error. I think this is because the list of dates that I want to filter are not always in the files I'm using. Sometimes I use specific periods within this range. How can I fix this?

Comment: Where are you getting the error?  It looks like the link to the csv file you provided is not working now, so I can't test it out against your actual file.  Are some of your rows missing some of the fields?  The access of row[2] and row[3] will cause that error if some rows have fewer than 4 fields (ie don't have a date or id).

Comment: The file should be up again: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ue976gk34qkj2ch/my_file.csv?dl=0

Comment: The problem is your csvreader creation.  It expects a file and not a filename.  Change `for row in csv.reader('my_file.csv', delimiter='\t')` to `for row in csv.reader(open('my_file.csv','r'), delimiter='\t')`

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend using `pandas`: it's great for filtering tables. Nice and readable.

```
import pandas as pd

# assumes the csv contains a header, and the 2 columns of interest are labeled "mydate" and "identifier"
# Note that "date" is a pandas keyword so not wise to use for column names
df = pd.read_csv(inputFilename, parse_dates=[2])  # assumes mydate column is the 3rd column (0-based)

df = df[~df.identifier.str.contains('ddd:11')]  # filters out all rows with 'ddd:11' in the 'identifier' column
# then filter out anything not inside the specified date ranges:
df = df[((pd.to_datetime("1951-01-01") <= df.mydate) & (df.mydate <= pd.to_datetime("1951-12-31"))) |
        ((pd.to_datetime("1962-07-01") <= df.mydate) & (df.mydate <= pd.to_datetime("1962-12-31")))]

df.to_csv(outputFilename)
```

See [Pandas Boolean Indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)

Answer (score 0):

My kinda approach workds like this -

```
import csv 
import re
import datetime

field_id = 'ddd:11'




d1 = datetime.date(1951,1,01) #change the start date
d2 = datetime.date(1951,12,31) #change the end date
diff = d2 - d1
date_list = []
for i in range(diff.days + 1):
    date_list.append((d1 + datetime.timedelta(i)).isoformat())
with open('mwevers_example_2016.01.02-07.25.55.csv','rb') as csv_file:

    reader = csv.reader(csv_file)

    for row in reader:

        for date in date_list:
            if row[3] == date:
                print row
                var = re.search('\\b'+field_id,row[2])
                if bool(var) == True:

                    print 'olalala'#here you can make a function to copy those rows into another file or any list
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll try and see if I can get it to work with the filter on ID and the print out.

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
import sys
import re
from datetime import datetime

csv.field_size_limit(sys.maxsize)

field_id = 'ddd:11'

dateranges = [("1951-01-01", "1951-12-31"),
              ("1962-07-01", "1962-12-31"),
              ("1963-01-01", "1963-09-30"),
              ("1965-07-01", "1965-07-30"),
              ("1965-10-01", "1965-10-31"),
              ("1966-04-01", "1966-11-30"),
              ("1969-01-01", "1989-12-31")
              ]
dateranges = list(map(lambda dr:
                      tuple(map(lambda x:
                            datetime.strptime(x, "%Y-%m-%d"), dr)),
                      dateranges))


def datefilter(x):
    x = datetime.strptime(x, "%Y-%m-%d")
    for r in dateranges:
        if r[0] <= x and r[1] >= x:
            return True
    return False


output = []
with open('my_file.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t', quotechar='"')
    next(reader)
    for row in reader:
        if datefilter(row[4]):
            var = re.search('\\b'+field_id, row[3])
            if bool(var) == False:
                output.append(row)
        else:
            output.append(row)


with open('output.csv', 'w') as outputfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outputfile, delimiter='\t', quotechar='"')
    writer.writerows(output)
```